# I'm trying to load a TSV file into a Hive Table, but unable to load it as it is giving me null values

Tags: sql, hive, tabs, hiveql

I created a table in Hive with below definition:

```
Create table Movie(Rank Int,Name String,Actor String,Year String)
Row format delimited
Fields terminated by "/t"
Stored as textfile;
```

After feeding the the above definition. I'm trying to load a self created (tab separated file, which I created on my own) and trying to load that from local. Once it is getting loaded on doing

```
select * from Movie;
```

it is giving me null values.

Can anyone please help me here as when I trying to the same thing with CSV files the query is showing all records. Please help

Comment: how does the input file look like -- can you share a small sample? how are you loading it into the table?

Comment: what is your load command ?